# Login failed for user 'rpa'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Tags: sql-server, apache-superset

I am trying to connect from **Superset** to SQL Server, using the pyodbc driver, which I already have installed from [this source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu17)

It is important to mention that I am already connected to SQL Server from my python project using the same pydobc driver and clearly obviously with the same credentials.

But I get a login error, I have seen documentation about this error and I think they parameterize the password using PWD and UID. But in this case I need to connect from Superset, what can I do?

This is the URI scheme that I am using to connect via pyodbc:

```
mssql+pyodbc://user:Password@Host,Port/DBname?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server?Trusted_connection
```

[image: Superset Output Screenshot]

Comment: If it's a trusted connection, why are you providing the username and password?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Is the login using SQL login or Windows Authentication login (aka Trusted Connection aka Integrated Security)

Comment: Charlieface, there I am using is the SQL login.

Comment: Lamu, I forgot to put the = no (trusted_connection = no) but that is not the problem as such.

Comment: Dale K, Thanks for the suggestion, any answer to help me with my question?

Answer (score 0):

```
mssql+pymssql://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<HOST>:1433/<DatabaseName>/?Encrypt=yes
```

This is the correct formart of the connection url. Replace the Username, Password, Host and Database with your own.